# Grep for lines with alternating pattern A and pattern B in text file

Tags: grep

Can grep be used to search for alternating patterns, i.e. first pattern A, then pattern B, then pattern A, then pattern B, etc.

I have a txt-file like this:

```
some lines
some line containing pattern B
some lines
some line containing pattern A
some line containing pattern B
some line containing pattern B
some line containing pattern A
some line containing pattern A
some line containing pattern B
```

I like to grep lines with alternating pattern A and pattern B. Like this:

```
some lines
some line containing pattern B  <- Don't take this (no A before)
some lines
some line containing pattern A  <- Take
some line containing pattern B  <- Take
some line containing pattern B  <- Don't take this (no A before)
some line containing pattern A  <- Take
some line containing pattern A  <- Don't take this (no B before)
some line containing pattern B  <- Take
```

So my final output is to be:

```
some line containing pattern A
some line containing pattern B
some line containing pattern A
some line containing pattern B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do what you want.

```
 awk '{m=a>b?a:b;} /pattern A/{a=NR} /pattern B/{b=NR}(m&&m==a&&a<b)||(m&&m==b&&b<a)' awkx
```

**DEMO**

```
lo@ubuntu:~$ awk '{m=a>b?a:b;} /pattern A/{a=NR} /pattern B/{b=NR}(m&&m==a&&a<b)||(m&&m==b&&b<a)' awkx
some line containing pattern A
some line containing pattern B
some line containing pattern A
some line containing pattern B
```